# How do I disable the JQuery click handler temporarily while an animation is running?

Tags: jquery, html, event-handling, click, onclicklistener

I'm still relatively new to JQuery, and I'm confused about how to solve the following issue. I want to temporarily disable the two flip functions (that respond to click events) until after the fade animation finishes.

With what I have below, the functions still run while the animations are going, so both divs (card-back and card-content) show at the same time.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#card-back").hide();
  $(".flip-back").hide();

  function firstflip(){
    $(".flip-back").show();
    $(".flip").hide();
    $("#card-content").fadeToggle("fast");
    $("#card-back").delay(300).fadeToggle("fast");
  }

  function secondflip(){
    $(".flip-back").hide();
    $(".flip").show();
    $("#card-back").fadeToggle("fast");
    $("#card-content").delay(300).fadeToggle("fast");
  }

  $(".flip").click(function(){
    $(".flip-back").unbind("click");
    firstflip();
    setTimeout(function(){
      $(".flip-back").bind("click",secondflip);
    },2000);
  });

  $(".flip-back").click(function(){
    $(".flip").unbind("click");
    secondflip();
    setTimeout(function(){
      $(".flip").bind("click",firstflip);
    },2000);
  });

});
```

Appreciate any help I can get on this matter!

EDIT: Just for clarity, I'm okay now on the fade in-fade out separation, but I need help on how to delay the re-bind of the click to the flip function (to avoid the queue of animations stacking up with multiple clicks in a row).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than an arbitrary delay before binding the new event handler (using `setTimeout`) you can pass a callback to [the `fadeToggle` function](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) which is executed once the animation is completed. This can be used both to show the new click target (which I assume is a button of some sort) and bind an event to it.

Meanwhile, rather than using anonymous functions for your event handlers which then call the named `firstFlip` and `secondFlip`, just put all your logic in the named functions and pass those as the event handlers. (You seem to be doing this when re-binding, but not when doing it the first time.)

See comments in the edited code below for what has changed:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#card-back").hide();
  $(".flip-back").hide();

  function firstflip(){
    // Hide button and remove this click event until next flip completes
    $(".flip").unbind('click').hide();
    $("#card-content").fadeToggle("fast");
    $("#card-back").delay(300).fadeToggle("fast", function(){
       // Once fully displayed, show button and bind next click handler
       $(".flip-back").show().bind("click",secondflip);
    });
  }

  function secondflip(){
    // Hide button and remove this click event until next flip completes
    $(".flip-back").unbind('click').hide();
    $("#card-back").fadeToggle("fast");
    $("#card-content").delay(300).fadeToggle("fast", function(){
       // Once fully displayed, show button and bind next click handler
       $(".flip").show().bind("click",firstflip);
    });
  }

  // Bind initial event (no need to bind secondflip yet, as firstflip will remove it anyway)
  $(".flip").bind("click",firstflip);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [Callback](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp), a feature that will make a function wait for another function to finish before performing.

Code is something like this:

```
function firstflip(){
    $(".flip-back").show();
    $(".flip").hide();
    $("#card-content").fadeToggle("fast",function(){
         $("#card-back").delay(300).fadeToggle("fast");
    });

}
```

Comment: In callback shoud be also `$(".flip-back").hide();` and `$(".flip").show();` from `secondflip`

Comment: Wow, that w3schools page is a pretty feeble attempt at explaining what a callback is. I guess it's technically true in the narrow sense of "jQuery's Effects system allows you to define callbacks for when an effect has completed". See also http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: Thanks! That's definitely new to me, and was helpful in separating the fade in/fade out. But my problem had more to do with someone clicking very rapidly, causing the animation queue to pile up. I need to somehow unbind secondflip, perform firstflip, and then rebind secondflip after a full second to address this issue. Just not sure how to go about it syntax-wise. Thanks again!

Comment: @IMSoP I agree with you in some points you're trying to make there. w3schools, to me, adopts 'as long as it works' principle which is found helpful by most people who are needing a quick fix rather than complete understanding of what is going on (yes, that wasn't an ideal case). Thanks for the tips on your link but they're not offering a solution. They had the idea and effort by starting up the page, it is a shame that they didn't start up a more comprehensive version of w3schools.

Comment: @Chris'o Well, for jQuery, the obvious place to look is the rather comprehensive official jQuery documentation. If someone needed a general introduction to callbacks (which that page isn't) they'd be looking for a Javascript (or even programming concepts) tutorial, not something jQuery-specific. As for the proponents of w3fools starting up better documentation sites, did you not see the links to recommended resources?

Comment: @IMSoP Yes I did, they are very useful links in fact. But I often found my self in a position of not knowing what should I am after to solve my problem like this fella asking the question above and callback itself is not quite a self-explanatory term. You have your point there, and it's good :) , by saying that w3schools is not a total answer for your question, but it's opening a path for people in doing research of what they are after.